# Position of central maxima when source is not in line with the slit

Tags: visible-light, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, superposition

[image]

If the source is placed at S1, the central maxima would be at the centre of the screen (in line with the slit).

However, if the source is shifted to S2, would this mean that the central maximum shifts to point A on the screen? If so, why?

I ask this in the context of Rayleigh's Criterion. In many images relating to reayleigh criterion, I see two sources placed side by side that are not directly in line with the slit. It seems to show that the central maxima from each source shifts in the direction that the source shifts towards. I would like to understand why this is the case?